# Bibliography does not appear

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

In my `.tex` document I have

```
[...]
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{amsplain}
\bibliography{bibliografie}

\end{document}
```

And I have the `bibliografie.bib` file in the same folder. However, why the bibliography does not appear at the end of the document?
And `bibliografie.bib` contains the following:

```
@BOOK{texbook,
   author = "Donald E. Knuth",
   title= "The {{\TeX}book}",
   publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
   year = 1984
   }

@BOOK{latexbook,
   author = "Leslie Lamport",
   title = "{\LaTeX \rm:} {A} Document Preparation System",
   publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
   year = 1986
   }
```

Comment: It's not necessary to sign your questions (as there is already a box with your username below it) or to begin them with a greeting.

Comment: maybe i'm missing something, but unless the system you're using is set up to run `bibtex` automatically, the absence of a `.bbl` file will mean that there is nothing for latex to read, and therefore no bibliography will ever appear in your document.

Comment: Are you (qwerty) processing your document through bibtex? You need to compile your file (let's call it `test.tex`) in the following way: `pdflatex test`, `bibtex test`, `pdflatex test`, and `pdflatex test`.

Comment: Note : You have to build the bibliography too, by clicking on F11 (or go to >Tools>BibTex). If you still have the same problem, try [that](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/249033/178234). Good luck !

Comment: simply put the lines `\begin{thebibliography}{..} ..... \end{thebibliography}` into a tex file, say `biblio.tex` and just `\include` it after \backmatter in `main.tex`. Problem solved. It is adhoc but does the job! Neither solution in any forum actually worked for me but this one did.

Answer (score 22):

In my case it was fault of editing tool. I was using TexMaker and it did not showed bibliography, because it was not enabled in build settings (preferences). Hope this helps somebody using TexMaker.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem as you, and was already doing what the other answers suggest doing.

I'm using TexMaker, and found that the problem was the option 'Use a "build" subdirectory for output files', found in the tab 'Commands' in the "Configure TexMaker" dialog window. When checked, all the citations appear as question marks, and the bibliography doesn't show. After I unchecked it, citations started working and the bibliography appeared.

[image: Option that must be unchecked]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Are you sure that this will solve the OP? I think the other supposted answers should solved the problem correctly.

Comment: Thank you.

Well, I posted this because the other options didn't solve my problem, and I learned this was a solution to my problem.

If someone were to have the same problem as I did,  their question would be the same as OP's, so I thought it would be pertinent to also have this answer here.

Answer (score 1):

The following minimal example works well.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{bibliografie.bib}
@BOOK{texbook,
   author = "Donald E. Knuth",
   title= "The {{\TeX}book}",
   publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
   year = 1984
   }

@BOOK{latexbook,
   author = "Leslie Lamport",
   title = "{\LaTeX \rm:} {A} Document Preparation System",
   publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
   year = 1986
   }

\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[english]{amsbook}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\Blinddocument
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{amsplain}
\bibliography{bibliografie}
\end{document}
```

Please learn how to create a minimal example.

Comment: Marco, but that code where should be placed? all the code is in a .tex file, or..?

Comment: The part between `\begin{filecontents*}{bibliografie.bib}` and `\end{filecontents*}` will be written in a file called `bibliografie.bib` when you run the code Marco posted. The other part is a simple `.tex` file.

Comment: @qwerty: the bib-file will create in the same folder. I can also split the code and after this I can use input or include. The result doesn't change. What problem do you have?

Comment: And \RequirePackage{filecontents} where should be placed?

Comment: Ok, i've split the code, so in my .bib file i have The part between \begin{filecontents*}{bibliografie.bib} and \end{filecontents*} and the other in the .tex file, but the bibliography is still not shown..

Comment: Do you compile the main file by bibtex? I repeat my information that we need a working example that shows the problem.

Comment: Ok, so i have the file bibliografie.bib and in TexnicCenter under the "Build" menu i have the BibTex menu item, which compiles the .bib file, but this menu item is disabled.. Why?

Comment: @qwerty: I have no Windows. Try the following. Open the aux-file with TeXnicCenter and maybe the menue item is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, you have to include some other content (in this case an invisible `\mbox`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\mbox{}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{amsplain}
\bibliography{bibliografie}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think that this is true

Comment: @Thorsten Maybe not, but it does not work without the `\mbox` so it is a quick solution. It says that _biblio.bbl_ and _biblio.aux_ are missing which is logical, because the first run on the _biblio.tex_ file tries to compile an empty document.

Comment: @Harald: But where do you have a problem? The compilation of an empty document (first compilation) isn't an error.

Comment: It just says `No File ... .aux` and `No File ... .bbl` which cannot be considered as an error.

Comment: @Thorsten Yes, you are right. I have made a wrong assumption, sorry. Nevertheless, my solution works and I am eager to know what causes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are first stumbling upon this search result, looking for an answer on this question while not matching the code in the original post, the could be that your `\bibliographystyle{...}` is commented out, is missing or has an illegal argument. There should be exactly one `\bibliographystyle{}` in your document.

When I was working in a well-known online LaTeX editor, I figured out, `\bibliographystyle{}` is required for compiling the bibliography. Uncommenting it made it show up.