# \printbibliography not doing anything

Tags: biblatex, texstudio

I'm relatively new to latex, and I'm trying to get a test bibliography working. I'm just going through the sharelatex section on biblatex (https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Bibliography_management_with_biblatex) and am just running their example code. However, instead of showing a few lines of text with citations within and then a list of references, I only get the text with citations. The list of references is not shown at all.

I'm using TexStudio, if that means anything.

The code in question is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\begin{document}
    Let's cite! The Einstein's journal paper \cite{einstein} and the Dirac's 
    book \cite{dirac} are physics related items. 

    \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

and sample.bib contains:

```
@article{einstein,
author =       "Albert Einstein",
title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
[{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
volume =       "322",
number =       "10",
pages =        "891--921",
year =         "1905",
DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004",
keywords =     "physics"
}

@book{dirac,
title={The Principles of Quantum Mechanics},
author={Paul Adrien Maurice Dirac},
isbn={9780198520115},
series={International series of monographs on physics},
year={1981},
publisher={Clarendon Press},
keywords = {physics}
}

@online{knuthwebsite,
author    = "Donald Knuth",
title     = "Knuth: Computers and Typesetting",
url       = "http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/abcde.html",
keywords  = "latex,knuth"
}

@inbook{knuth-fa,
author = "Donald E. Knuth",
title = "Fundamental Algorithms",
publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
year = "1973",
chapter = "1.2",
keywords  = "knuth,programming"
}
```

EDIT:
Just to clarify,
Actual Output
[image: Output]
Expected Output
[image: Expected Output]

EDIT 2:

Adding biber as the default bibliography still gives the same output, but also gives the following messages:

```
    Process started: biber.exe "test"

Use of uninitialized value $llabel in concatenation (.) or string at C:\Users\~\AppData\Local\Temp\par-5072696d617263682d4956\cache-6bef6bfac2f8155f13b160f6720d3dbe6a10b684\inc\lib/Biber.pm line 675.

Use of uninitialized value in string eq at C:\Users\~\AppData\Local\Temp\par-5072696d617263682d4956\cache-6bef6bfac2f8155f13b160f6720d3dbe6a10b684\inc\lib/Biber/SortLists.pm line 77.

INFO - This is Biber 1.8
INFO - Logfile is 'test.blg'
INFO - Reading 'test.bcf'
WARN - Warning: Found biblatex control file version 2.7, expected version 2.5
INFO - Found 2 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'sample.bib' for section 0
INFO - Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'sample.bib'

Process exited with error(s)
```

With bibtex it gives the following:

```
    Process started: bibtex.exe "test"

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9)
The top-level auxiliary file: test.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file test.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file test.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file test.aux
(There were 3 error messages)
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you run either `biber` or `bibtex` after the first compilation and then compile again?

Comment: I believe so. I went to Tool->Commands->bibtex/biber, let that run and then recompiled and built. No difference.

Comment: Just to be clear. What output exactly are you seeing? Are you seeing in-line citations that are formatted properly, and you're just missing the bibliography, or are you seeing the cite keys in bold in-line? It might be helpful if you were to post a picture. See [this answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/2137/32888) about how to post a picture when you don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Since `biblatex` is specified without specific backend, `biber` is used. TeXStudio must be configured to use `biber` then. The example works out of the box for me (doing Linux command line compilation, not using editor stuff)

Comment: Maybe [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) helps you to make TexStudio use Biber. Other than that a more detailed description of the symptoms would be quite helpful to investigate the problem further.

Comment: Adding the biber backend doesn't make anything difference. I'll try it on a linux machine when I can, but as I'm switching between linux and windows all the time I also need to get it to work with TexStudio.

Comment: This may be the well known and unresolved biblatex cache bug. Try deleting the cache -- see for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140814/biblatex-biber-fails-with-a-strange-error-about-missing-recode-data-xml-file as to where to find it. Here is another link which will help you find cache http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/216191/biber-biblatax-problem-no-such-file-or-directory-in-cache

Comment: If you don't specify a backend via the `backend` option you will have to use Biber, so running BibTeX will not help at all. If you want to use BibTeX, go with `backend=bibtex`. I would, however, use Biber if possible. There seem to be several problems, first your Biber and `biblatex` versions don't match please update both and make sure their versions match. Secondly you seem to experience [this classic Biber problem](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140814/35864).

Comment: Thanks guys! After updating biber etc. some missing packages were installed. After that I needed to remove the cache, but everything is working properly now.

Comment: I voted to close as a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140814/35864 since the problem seems to have been resolved by deleting the cache and updating Biber (see OP's self-answer below).

Comment: Sure. How do I do that? Or will the mods take care of it?

Comment: Normally, the review process on this site takes care of that. If you agree, with the close vote however, I think you can also vote to close your own question (not entirely sure here).

Comment: I would vote not to close this. Enough folk are experiencing this bug repeatedly without any resolution that it needs to be kept on the agenda. I earlier tried to debug this, a lot of people put in effort and then it was closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update packages (I was using MikTex as a package manager), and then remove the cache as explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140814/biblatex-biber-fails-with-a-strange-error-about-missing-recode-data-xml-file). Compile, compile bibliography, recompile and build.
Thanks to Aubrey Blumsohn and moewe.